# Do headless chickens run around?

Tags: physiology, zoology, quotes

It's a clichè that is constantly repeated by the likes of Gordon Ramsey:

> You are running around like headless chickens!

[image: headless chicken]

<sup>[source](http://www.successcreationtoolbox.com/futureinspiredbusinessowner/are-you-running-around-like-a-headless-chicken/)</sup>

Also, for example, they do in [South Park animations](http://www.southparkstudios.com/clips/222638/bailout)

Do headless chicken run around? After all, why wouldn't they collapse?

Comment: They do in [South Park animations](http://www.southparkstudios.com/clips/222638/bailout)

Comment: If you remove the whole head, it will still move but only spasmodically, no walking or running. If you remove the most of the head but leave the brainstem (bottom 1/4 inch of the skull), then the chicken's balance and walking centers are just FINE. All it lacks is any form of guidance. It can live in this state until it bleeds to death, of if bleeding is stopped, until it drops from dehydration.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes they do, or at least kind of do.

They move after decapitation in a kind of jumping-running-flapping motion, and can be seen in the videos getting out of containers, or traveling several dozen meters away.

Searching for "headless chickens run around" gives a bunch of YouTube videos. All depicting decapitated chickens running around, flapping their wings and jumping. Here are some examples:

**Caution: NSFW. Contains graphic content.**

- [A decapitated chicken running around in the yard until finally succumbing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HksE-7aYmIw)
- [A decapitated chicken jumps out of a bucket and running around until finally succumbing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt0NGCckfzU)
- [Shows the decapitation of a chicken and then the chicken jumps around, and another chicken decapitated and then flapping while it's held down](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swuD2rX3hfQ)

Comment: I am completely nitpicking here, but those videos don't show chickens *running* by any measure.

Comment: In the first and 3rd videos it's kind of running-jumping, but in all videos and other videos I didn't put the chickens move a considerable distance after decapitation.

Comment: Anecdote: When I was a kid we had chickens (and geese). I had to behead chickens once in a while, and yes, their legs and wings work furiously for maybe 15 seconds or so.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey same happens when chicken's neck is broken. I saw that once *(on a big chicken)*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are running around, until they dead.

Here is a story of Mike. A chicken refused to dead after beheaded.

[The chicken that lived for 18 months without a head](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-34198390)

> Seventy years ago, a farmer beheaded a chicken in Colorado, and it
>   refused to die. Mike, as the bird became known, survived for 18 months
>   and became famous. But how did he live without a head for so long,
>   asks Chris Stokel-Walker.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mike is a famous story, but it is the story of what happens when a chicken *doesn't* die, when *most* of its head is chopped off. It isn't representative of the more typical behaviour that the expression is derived from.